# not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header:

Tags: http, request, postman

I have a valid bearer token which I set in the appropriate section of my POSTMAN request as shown in the picture below:
[image]

Then in Headers, I see it is set:
[image]
but then when I send the request I get back 403 response with this message:

not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer eyJ...'

To my best knowledge this has always used to work.
Adding an '=' between the bearer and the token does not work either
Any ideas as to why its not anymore would be very much welcomed.

and

Comment: Authorization's Type selected "Bearer Token"  means automatically to add in Header with Key is "Authorization" and value is "Bearer token_value". that is correct should not add '='. Your 403 error means your token  don't have a permission for that POST call. Not a token itself issue , it has have a privilege issue. expired, invalid, or lacks the necessary permissions to access the requested POST call.